# Move object value from one array of objects to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays of objects and need to move the value from the 2nd array in to the first array object with the same id.

```
array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A'},{id:2, location: 'B'},{id:3, location: 'C'},{id:4, location: 'D'}]

array2 = [{id:1, value: 123},{id:2, value: 5466},{id:3, value: 89484},{id:4, value: -4.215}]
```

Ive tried merging them but i just end up with duplicate objects.

how i want it to end up looking like

```
array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A', value: 123},{id:2, location: 'B', value: 5466},{id:3, location: 'C', value: 89484},{id:4, location: 'D', value: -4.215}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may traverse your *base* array with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) along the way to lookup another array for matching `id`:

```js
const array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A'},{id:2, location: 'B'},{id:3, location: 'C'},{id:4, location: 'D'}],
      array2 = [{id:1, value: 123},{id:2, value: 5466},{id:3, value: 89484},{id:4, value: -4.215}],
      
      result = array1.map(o => ({...o, ...array2.find(_o => _o.id == o.id)}))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet

```js
array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A'},{id:2, location: 'B'},{id:3, location: 'C'},{id:4, location: 'D'}]

array2 = [{id:1, value: 123},{id:2, value: 5466},{id:3, value: 89484},{id:4, value: -4.215}]

let result = array1.map(obj => {
  return {
        ...array2.filter(obj2 => obj2.id === obj.id)[0],
        ...obj
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This will loop unnecessarily throughout the entire `array2` even when the match (unique) was already found. So, [`.find()`-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793434/11299053) is more optimal from performance standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
array1.map( // build a second array with the new objects
       el => Object.assign( // create the merged object
               el, //          from the current object
               array2.find( // with the object in array2 with the same id
                    obj => obj.id == el.id
               )
       )
)
```

Comment: This would also mutate `array1` behind the scenes, so using `.map()` rather than `.forEach()` doesn't really make much sense. If you need to stay immutable, you would need to do `Object.assign({}, el, array2.find..`

Answer (score 0):

If index are same you can map and spread the object like below

```js
const array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A'},{id:2, location: 'B'},{id:3, location: 'C'},{id:4, location: 'D'}];

const array2 = [{id:1, value: 123},{id:2, value: 5466},{id:3, value: 89484},{id:4, value: -4.215}];

const merged = array1.map((a,i)=>({...a, ...array2[i]}));
 
console.log(merged);
```

If the index are not same then you can do like below

```js
const array1 = [{id:1, location: 'A'},{id:2, location: 'B'},{id:3, location: 'C'},{id:4, location: 'D'}];

const array2 = [{id:1, value: 123},{id:2, value: 5466},{id:3, value: 89484},{id:4, value: -4.215}];
  
const merged = array1.map(a=>({...a, ...array2.find(a2=>a2.id==a.id)}));

console.log(merged);
```